# objective function derivative

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative

Let's assume I have an objective function:

$f(x) = x^2-b$

If I find partial derivative w.r.t $b$, I get:

$\frac{\partial f }{\partial b} = -1$.

But if I want to minimize it, I would set it to zero:

$0=1$

Now, isn't this bizarre? How can zero be one? How to interpret this?

Comment: It I shard to understand what you are looking for without context.  Taking $A$ as a function of $b$ it is plain that it is unbounded and can be made as large or as small (i.e. negative) as you like by choosing $b$.  See [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is natural as $f$ is linear in $b$. There exist no local minima. Basically derivative is constant and function value goes on decreasing as you move in that direction. This is similar to $f(x) = x+3$, you cannot maximize or minimize the function w.r.t $x$ by setting derivative equal to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes in this manner it makes sense. If b would be squared so the function would be: x^2+b^2, then b=0, which infact is true.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You can confirm the optimality by checking the second derivative.